# CouchDB doc._local_seq property index through couchdb-lucene

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

CouchDB 1.6 has added the ability to pass `_local_seq` (or seq) of the doc to the view if the design-doc has `options.local_seq = true`. I want to use with couchdb-lucene but I am unable to make it work?

Here is the design doc:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/changes",
   "_rev": "5-e894a1ea6a6768acb22e6597425de4b2",
   "language": "javascript",
   "options": {
       "local_seq": true
   },
   "fulltext": {
       "replication": {
           "index": "function(doc) {\n  if(doc.context){\n\n    var ret = new Document();    \n    ret.add(doc.context,{field:'context',store:'yes'});\n    ret.add(doc._id,{field:'id',store:'yes',analyze:false});\n    ret.add(doc._rev,{field:'rev',store:'yes',analyze:false});\n    ret.add(doc._local_seq,{field:'seq',store:'yes',analyze:false});\n\n    return ret;\n  }\n}   "
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to open a feature request to CouchDB-Lucene: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/issues — it doesn’t look like it has that feature enabled yet, if it is at all possible.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. I have opened an issue: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/issues/195